# Handle file in Azure Function in PowerShell uploaded via Postman

Tags: azure-functions

I have uploaded a file via Postman in the body (form-data) of a POST request. This file is to be handled in Azure Function written in PowerShell. How the file can be handled so that it needs to be attached to SharePoint online list item.